# "Thread 1: signal Sigabrt" when calling requestLocation()

Tags: swift

try to use `CLlocationManager().requestLocation()` to get user's current location. But the app crashes and shows signal Sigabrt. I know it is probably because of unconnected outlets, so I make sure they were all connected but the compiler still pops out this warning. I had properly implemented
the keys in p.list by the way.

Interestingly, when I change `requestLocation()` to `startUpdatingLocation()`, things work.

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
}
```

I hope someone could tell me what I did wrong, or should I just replace requestLocation() with startUpdatingLocation().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple states in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation) that you have to implement these delegate methods if you wish to use `requestLocation()`:

`locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` and `locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)`.

The below piece of code works for me.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestLocation()
        }

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("LOCATIONS: \(locations)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
    }

}
```